# Transforming array cell in a table to rows in another table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table (table1) which has just one cell. The contents of this cell are in an array format. I need to convert the contents of this cell into separate rows in a new table (table2)

Example table 1 looks like this:-

[![element
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'corge', 'garply', 'waldo', 'fred']][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLtyr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLtyr.png)

Example table 2 should look like this:-
[image]

I have gone through the big query documentation about the arrays and use of UNNEST operator.

The below logic will work:-
'''SELECT *
FROM UNNEST(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'corge', 'garply', 'waldo', 'fred'])
  AS element'''

However, I need to read the array from the cell in table 1 and create table 2.

Any help on this will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT element
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(element) element
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'corge', 'garply', 'waldo', 'fred'] element
)
SELECT element
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(element) element
```

with output

```
Row element  
1   foo  
2   bar  
3   baz  
4   qux  
5   corge    
6   garply   
7   waldo    
8   fred
```

Now, you can use above to create new table as in below example

```
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table2` AS    
SELECT element
FROM `project.dataset.table1`,
UNNEST(element) element
```